# unable to move files to others dirs on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website in wordpress and something has happened that I've never seen before. I tried to do uploads, the first upload worked, but the second always show me a error message like this:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/home/wwwtmp/phpZJvzfO' to '/sistemas/htdocs/wwwsuabios/wp-content/uploads/Maid-with-the-Flaxen-Hair1.mp3' in /sistemas/htdocs/wwwsuabios/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 328
```

I already changed the permissions of dirs to 755, after I changed to 777, I changed the owner of the files and dirs of all website to the same owner. If I delete the file of the first upload, I can do another upload, but the second show me the same error again.

PS: all the dirs and files are of the root user. And all created by the admin system of wordpress is of wwwrun user.

Comment: It's the permissions of the uploaded file that prevent it from being overwritten.

Comment: Suspectus, i didn't understand your observation. How can i change the permission of the uploaded file in the same time that i do the upload?

Comment: @Loan - You don't without root access to the server